# FQDN as a Forwarder in BIND

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, fqdn

My provider is changing his DNS infrastructure and we have to change forwarders IP to fqdn (Bind). Is there any option to handle that kind of change?

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible and illogical. DNS is used to obtain host names; you can not configure a name server by name, because it should be already accessible to be able to resolve that name. This is why we always configure raw IP or IPv6 addresses of upstream servers.